# My domain emails is detected as spam

Tags: dns, gmail, spf, google-workspace, dkim

I have a domain connected to Gsuite, but when i send any emails from my email domain is detected as spam with message "Be careful with this message. It contains content that's typically used to steal personal information."

I added google DMIK and SPF and also i added DMARK Record.

Here is a screenshot from https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/:

[Output from google toolbox checker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyimE.png)
I am using CDN and am adding all the records in Cloudflare.

Any idea why any normal email is detected as spam with this message ?

Answer (score 1):

My favourite go to gadget is `https://www.mail-tester.com/` which offers the opportunity to very easily and quicky determinate what issues causes this classification.

Besides, SPF DKIM and DMARC there are a variety of other things to consider: like the IP origin header, the message content whether its bulk or not, if the email is marked on behalf of others etc.

Since you mentioned CDN and cloudflare, did you double check whether you are using its [DDoS protection](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/ddos-mitigation/)? If so, other IP addresses are routed and appointed in its DNS.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you are using an mail server to send email which is not whitelisted in spf records.

May be share a dig on MX and CNAME records of your domain.